# Find the number of measurements so that our iuncertainty is less than 2%

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, confidence-interval, standard-error

> The results of a certain experiment whose true value is about 10.0 cm, follow a
> normal distribution with standard deviation of 1.0 cm. How many measurements will we have to do
> so that our uncertainty about the true value at the $90\%$ confidence level is less
> than $2\%$? Assume that systematic uncertainty is negligible.

So I did this with the following formula $$Error=Z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=0.02\Rightarrow n=\frac{Z_{\alpha/2}^2\sigma^2}{0.02^2}$$ being $Z_{\alpha/2}$ the value on the normal distribution that leaves $\alpha/2$ on the right side of $Z$, $\sigma$ the standard deviation and $p=0.9$ the confidence level which then $\alpha$ is $p=1-\alpha$. But the book says I'm wrong, what's happening here? And also I haven't used the info *"the results of a certain experiment whose true value is about 10cm"*. Is **that** where I'm missing?

Comment: Is it just 2%=0.02 or 2% of 10 =0.2?

Comment: @callculus42 can you please expand on why it should be 2% of 10?

Comment: @callculus42 yeah can you expand on that?

Comment: @Acedium20 "Less than 2% " can be probably.understood in both ways. Why do they not just write 0.02? Nevertheless: If it is 0.02, do you comprehend my answer?

Comment: @callculus42 the thing is that the book actually uses 2% of 10, and I would want to understand the logic behind that, I do understand 0.02 but want to understand why would it be 0.2

Comment: @Acedium20 The phrase of the exercise is a little bit unclear. An unambiguously phrase would be "...  confidence level is less than **2% of the mean**" But the equation itself is clear? Do you see the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: @callculus42 ohhh now I understand then, it makes it clearer with the "of the mean", otherwise it's very unclear, I think everythings fine now, thanks!

Comment: @Acedium20 If all is claer feel free to accept the answer. Btw, what is the answer of the book.

Comment: @callculus42 the book's answer for $n$ is $64.27$, after using the 2% of 10, which is why I asked for that perspective

Comment: Now everything is clear for me as well :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confidence interval is

$$\large{\left[\overline x-z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n} ; \ \overline x+z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}  \right]}$$

You have $\alpha=1-0.9=0.1$. Thus $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-\frac{0.1}{2}=1-0.05=0.95$.

And the width of the interval (uncertainty) is 2%. Thus

$2\cdot z_{0.95}\cdot \frac{1.0}{\sqrt n}=0.02\Rightarrow 1.64485\cdot \frac{1.0}{\sqrt n}=0.01$